# Vote extension for MediaWiki?

Tags: plugins, mediawiki

Those listed on their website are quite old and don't work with latest code. I tried, but not luck, the code is outdate. Anyone know a good plugin?

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to mention what kind of voting you have in mind (public, private, volume of candidates, voting system). I doubt there is and will be a catch-all solution.

Answer (score 0):

[VoteNY](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VoteNY) works with latest stable (1.24.2), [as far as I can see](https://wikiapiary.com/wiki/Extension:Vote) and [in my testing](http://en.userwiki.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Special:TopRatings) on a live wiki.